# Pull all {alternate_titles} fields for navigation menu, even if page is limit=1

Tags: ee2, channel-entries, categories, navigation

I'm using a sidebar navigation, that is embedded on an intro page and subsequent single article pages. This is my embedded navigation:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="{path='spice_2011/kiritimati'}" class="active_left">Kiritimati</a></li>
{exp:channel:entries channel="spice_kiritimati" category="not 268" disable="member_data|pagination" sort="desc" orderby="date"}         
<li><a href="{url_title_path='spice_2011/kiritimati_atlas'}" {alternate_title}</a></li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

This is how the content is displayed on the intro page:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="spice_kiritimati" category="268" disable="member_data|pagination" sort="desc" orderby="date"  }
```

All the titles of the articles show up in my embedded navigation on the intro page. Using the same embedded navigation, when I show pages that are limited to one article, using this code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="spice_kiritimati" disable="member_data|pagination" sort="desc" orderby="date" limit="1"  }
```

Only the one title, of the page you are on, shows up in the embedded navigation. Is there another way to handle how the embedded navigation is built, so that its not limited to the one article title, but shows all article titles, as on the intro page? I tried changing the limit=10 in the embedded navigation code, that didn't work. Neither did showing related categories, both tries were stabs in the dark.

I'm guessing I need to somehow grab all alternate titles in a channel, but can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `dynamic="no"` to the `{exp:channel:entries}` tag.

By default, it is dynamic, meaning it will look at the URL for information about which channel entry to show.

If you turn dynamic off, it will just do what you tell it in the parameters.